# git project inside git project with git 2.16

Tags: windows, git, github

I have a Github project in a folder `folder`, and in a subfolder `subfolder` of `folder` I have another Github project. The two Github accounts are different. I'm using Windows.

With `git 2.11.0.windows1`, when I am in `subfolder` and I do `git push`, then `git` asks me my username and my password, and everything works fine.

But with `git 2.16.1.windows4`, when I am in `subfolder` and I do `git push`, then `git` denies the permission:

```
remote: Permission to laustep/stlahblog.git denied to stla.
```

Here `stla` is my user name of the project in `folder`, not in `subfolder`. I don't know why `git` finds this user name. It is only given in the `config` file in `folder\.git`.

What should I do with `git 2.16.1` to push from `subfolder` ?

Comment: You can find out which `.git` directory Git is using by running `git rev-parse --git-dir` (for relative path, or `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir` for absolute path). It's more likely that Git is using cached credentials and your newer version of Git is fancier and is automatically remembering the cached credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Since your pushing code from subfolder(different project) you need to have a config file having your new user details in subfolder's .git folder. If that is not present  it will try to read details from global config file which can be stla.

Please execute below commands in subfolder , you might find some info

git remote -v
git config --list

Comment: Thanks. I've tried these commands. Everything looks normal. I have a config file for `subfolder`, and `git config --list` shows this config file. `git remote -v` prints the correct repo. There's no mention of stla.